# UIApplication.Main(args, null, typeof(AppDelegate)); << System.ArgumentNullException value cannot be null parameter name: input

Tags: xamarin.ios

this happens when i start the build on IOS

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
            // you can specify it here.

            UIApplication.Main(args, null, typeof(AppDelegate));
        }
```

[image]

I tried to see if it had to do with the firebase push notification that I started in appDelegate and I also tried to see if it was Xamarin.Essentials but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the exception and the code for AppDelegate?

Comment: I'm having the same issue here and seems that there is like no answers anywhere on this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an exception coming from the IOS main, and I can almost guarantee that nobody will be able to help you since it is most likely an unhandled exception in *your* code or how it interacts with a library.

I suggest wrapping the UIApplication.Main() method in a try/catch block. I was able to set breakpoint and catch a stacktrace pointing right to an interface method in my viewmodel.